# internal IP address vs 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, networking, ip

My web and database servers are on the same machine
when connecting to the database server I used the internal 192.168.1.15 address assigned by the router

Is there any difference latency-wise compared to using 127.0.0.1?

Is the OS smart enough to know that the 192 address is the same machine?
Will the packets even be sent to the router / leave the machine?

Comment: Linux is smart enough to not send such packets over the wire. I don't know about Windows.

Comment: If you do care about performance, a web site and its database instance should be installed on separate machines (then both of them can make great use of the memory). 127.0.0.1 maps to the loopback interface, and it does not always give you the best performance as you wished. A true network adapter won't slow you down much.

Comment: @MichaelHampton wasn't the original Windows TCP/IP stack taken from one of teh BSDs? In which case it might actually still be sane? :)

Comment: I know most about linux and when you are on the same machine there the third option is usually even better performance wise, namely to use a UNIX domain socket connection and you don’t even have to craft TCP/IP packets

Comment: Good question and surprisingly few answers...

Answer (score 0):

The main difference would be what machines beyond that one could access the database.  If you wanted to ensure that only the webserver running on that machine was the one to access that database you could have the database server only listen on 127.0.0.1 rather than on all addresses.

But either way if you use the 127.0.0.1 or it's 192.x.x.x address the traffic will not leave the machine and traverse the network.